# Pipe GET response to POST request as form-data

Tags: node.js, stream, pipeline, multipartform-data, form-data

I'm trying to read a video file from a URL (Amazon CloudFront) and stream it (upload it) with a `POST` request to Dailymotion using a NodeJS Lambda function.

Here's the code that I have:

```js
https.get(
  'https://cdn.mysite.com/video.mp4',
  videoStream => {
    videoStream.pipe(
      https.request(
        'https://upload-xx.xxx.dailymotion.com/upload?uuid=xxxxx&seal=xxxxx&extra=xxxxx', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        },
        body: {
          'Content-Disposition': 'form-data',
          'Content-Type': 'video/mp4',
          'file': videoStream
        }
      },
      (response) => {
        console.log('statusCode   :', response.statusCode);
        console.log('statusMessage:', response.statusMessage);
      })
    );
  },
  (response) => {
    console.log(response);
  }
);
```

Using the code above, I'm always getting this response from Dailymotion:

```bash
statusCode   : 422
statusMessage: Unproccessable Entity
```

Based on Dailymotion [**documentation**](https://developers.dailymotion.com/upload/#upload-video-steps):

> The video can actually be uploaded to the `upload_url` retrieved above by **making a POST HTTP request** using the `multipart/form-data` content type. The video data has to be contained in a `file` field.

How can I pass the piped chunks as `form-data` to the POST request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution using `request` and `form-data` libraries. Just:

1. Created a new form.
2. Appended the file to the form as a stream using `request`.
3. Submit the form.
4. Wait for the upload to end to send the `callback` back to the caller with the response.

If the file was uploaded successfully, the upload server will return a JSON object containing several fields, the only field you need to publish the video is the `url` one.

Here's a working copy of my Lambda function code:

```js
import request from 'request';
import FormData from 'form-data';

export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const form = new FormData();
  form.append('file', request('https://cdn.mysite.com/video.mp4'));
  form.submit({
    host: 'upload-XX.dcX.dailymotion.com',
    path: '/upload?uuid=XXXXX&seal=XXXXX&extra=XXXXX'
  }, (error, response) => {
    if (error) throw error;
    let body = '';
    response.on('data', chunk => {body += chunk.toString()});
    response.on('end', () => {callback(null, JSON.parse(body))});
    response.resume();
  });
};
```

### Update

Another solution using the `https` native module of Nodejs instead of the deprecated `request` library:

```js
import https from 'https';
import FormData from 'form-data';

export const handler = (event, context, callback) => {
  const form = new FormData();
  https.get('https://cdn.mysite.com/video.mp4', response => {
    form.append('file', response);
    form.submit(
      {
        host: 'upload-XX.dcX.dailymotion.com',
        path: '/upload?uuid=XXXXX&seal=XXXXX&extra=XXXXX'
      },
      (error, response) => {
        if (error) callback(error);
        let body = '';
        response.on('data', chunk => body += chunk.toString());
        response.on('end', () => callback(null, JSON.parse(body)));
        response.resume();
      }
    );
  });
};
```